# Planetary tails: How many have we observed yet?

Tags: exoplanet, mercury

Just recently I learned that [Mercury has a sodium tail](https://www.sciencealert.com/the-tail-of-mercury) and it is actually [well studied since long](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/messenger/media/seven-things.html):

> As a result, the planet has the appearance of a comet, with a tail that's been observed streaming nearly 3.5 million kilometres away from the planet.

This made me wonder about exoplanets with tails, like [WASP-69b](https://earthsky.org/space/jupiter-sized-exoplanet-wasp-69b-comet-like-tail). How many (exo)planets are known to have a tail?

#### References

- [Why would a planet form a cometlike tail under conditions of weaker rather than stronger solar wind?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/39774/why-would-a-planet-form-a-cometlike-tail-under-conditions-of-weaker-rather-than)

Comment: other tail questions: [How can Mercury's sodium tail be imaged?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/39094/7982) and [Why is sodium such a common ion for in ion tails?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/6266/7982) Do you think that just `tail` is the best and clearest name for a tag for planetary tails? I wonder if it should be "planetary-tail"since questions about cometary tails are more complex in nature, much more numerous and *already covered* by `comets`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, apart from WASP-69b, there has been reports of other exoplanets emitting some form of planetary tails. Let's start from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exoplanet):

> **KIC 12557548 b** is a small rocky planet, very close to its star, that is evaporating and leaving a trailing tail of cloud and dust like a comet. The dust could be ash erupting from volcanos and escaping due to the small planet's low surface-gravity, or it could be from metals that are vaporized by the high temperatures of being so close to the star with the metal vapor then condensing into dust.
>
> In June 2015, scientists reported that the atmosphere of **GJ 436 b** was
> evaporating, resulting in a giant cloud around the planet and, due to
> radiation from the host star, a long trailing tail 14 million km (9
> million mi) long.

---

More on the dust particles that is trailing from the exoplanets KIC 12557548 b as well as **KOI-2700b**:

> The observed tail lengths are consistent with dust grains composed of
> corundum (Al<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub>) or iron-rich silicate minerals (e.g., fayalite,
> Fe<sub>2</sub>SiO<sub>4</sub>). Pure iron and carbonaceous compositions are not favored. In
> addition, we estimate dust mass loss rates of 1.7 ± 0.5 M⊕ Gyr<sup>-1</sup> for
> KIC 12557548b, and > 0.007 M⊕ Gyr<sup>-1</sup> (1σ lower limit) for KOI-2700b.
>
> <sub>**Source**: Dusty tails of evaporating exoplanets, I. Constraints on the dust composition, R. van Lieshout1, M. Min and C. Dominik, A&A, Volume 572, December 2014, DOI: [10.1051/0004-6361/201424876](https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/full_html/2014/12/aa24876-14/aa24876-14.html)</sub>

---

> Astronomers using NASA's Hubble Space Telescope have confirmed the
> existence of a baked object that could be called a "cometary planet."
> The gas giant planet, named **HD 209458b**, is orbiting so close to
> its star that its heated atmosphere is escaping into space.
>
> <sub>**Source**: https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/hubble/science/planet-tail.html</sub>

---

> Astronomers have confirmed that the planet **Gliese 436b** seems to be
> trailing a gigantic, comet-like cloud of hydrogen.
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>**Source**: https://skyandtelescope.org/astronomy-news/exoplanet-with-a-comet-tail-06302015234/</sub>

---

> Disintegrating planets allow for the unique opportunity to study the
> composition of the interiors of small, hot, rocky exoplanets because
> the interior is evaporating and that material is condensing into dust,
> which is being blown away and then transiting the star. Their transit
> signal is dominated by dusty effluents forming a comet-like tail
> trailing the host planet **K2-22b**, making these good candidates for
> transmission spectroscopy.
>
> <sub>**Source**: Eva H. L. Bodman et al 2018 AJ 156 173, DOI: [10.3847/1538-3881/aadc60](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-3881/aadc60)</sub>